# Get TextBody for an email through the ews-java-api

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

It seems not to be possible to get email body as plain text if there is some in mime encoded mail. How to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. When you get the item
`ExchangeService.bindToItem(EmailMessage.class, itemId, PROPERTY_SET_TEXT_BODY).getBody()` use need use following property set and then set request body type to `BodyType.Text`

```
PropertySet PROPERTY_SET_TEXT_BODY = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body);
PROPERTY_SET_TEXT_BODY.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);
```